Plotting circle by center of circle and the radius in QGIS
I want to draw the circle by the center of the circle and the radius of the specified circle, just like in ArcGIS, to show the distance of the edge from the center of the circle and thus draw the circle. But I didn't find the right tool in QGIS.

A similar thread: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/484704/plotting-circle-by-center-of-circle-and-the-radius-in-qgis-using-python-console.


Enable the advanced digitizing tool
Start to create a circle with the Circle from a center point and another point tool
Optionally specify the radius manually by pressing the D key and entering the desired value (via @Bera)


