Plotting circle by center and radius in QGIS Python Console
Using QGIS's Python Console, I would like to be able to specify a coordinate in a given projection and draw a regular n-gon of a specific size centered on that point.
I can achieve the above if the projection is EPSG:4326:
vl = QgsVectorLayer("Polygon", "temp", "memory")
pr = vl.dataProvider()
f = QgsFeature()
f.setGeometry(QgsGeometry.fromPointXY(QgsPointXY(43,21)).buffer(5,24))
pr.addFeature(f)
vl.updateExtents() 
QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(vl)

This draws a circle around 43,21 (lng, lat) with a 5 unit (ie degree) radius (circle meaning: 24-gon). Screenshot:

If I could do this using arbitrary UTM zones for example, then I could draw a circle like many-gons using the Python Console. It would provide an alternative approach to the existing (and quite good) answer in this thread.
How can I draw a regular many-gon of a given projection using the Python Console?

When creating the vl with:
vl = QgsVectorLayer("Polygon", "temp", "memory")

try to extend its uri treated by the QgsVectorDataProvider with specifying the crs, see the parameters of the memory QgsVectorLayer:

crs=definition Defines the coordinate reference system to use for the
layer. definition is any string accepted by
QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem::createFromString()

vl = QgsVectorLayer("Polygon?crs=EPSG:25833", "temp", "memory")

Otherwise, see other answers in this thread: Defining the CRS for memory layer using PyQGIS
